# create a nested dictionary from two csv files

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested, key-value

I have two csv files
file1.csv:

```
ID,map1,map2  
a,x1,x2  
b,y1,  
c,z1,z2
```

file2.csv:

```
ID,map1Val1,map1Val2,map2Val1
a,a1,a2,l1
b,b1,b2,
c,c1,c2,n1
```

I want the output to look like:

```
{'ID': {'map1':['map1Val1','map1Val2'], 'map2':'map2Val1'},'a': {'x1':['a1','a2'], 'x2':'l1'},'b': {'y1':['b1','b2']},'c': {'z1':['c1','c2'], 'z2':'n1'},}
```

The I can't think of any way to create this. So far i have just a code to create a dictionary from one csv file:

```
import csv
new_data_dict = {}
with open("file1.csv", 'r') as map_file:
    mapping = csv.DictReader(map_file, delimiter=",")
    for row in mapping:
        new_data_dict= {row[0]:{row[1],row[2]}}
print new_data_dict
```

Output:

```
{"ID":{map1,map2}, "a":{x1,x2}, "b":{y1}, "a":{z1,z2}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more dynamic solution that allows you to pre-configure which columns from `file1` map to which columns from `file2`:

```
import csv

 = {'map1': ['map1Val1', 'map1Val2'],
              'map2': ['map2Val1']
              }

joined_data = dict()
joined_data['ID'] = column_map

with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    key_list = list(csv.DictReader(f1))
    value_list = list(csv.DictReader(f2))

for kl, vl in zip(key_list, value_list):
    inner = {}
    for key, value_list in column_map.items():
        if kl[key]:
            inner[kl[key]] = [vl[el] for el in value_list]

    joined_data[kl['ID']] = inner
```

The use of `csv.DictReader` lets us map  the data from each row into a `dict`, whose keys are (by default) given by the first row of the file. The two `DictReader` objects are cast to lists and iterated along using `zip`. Using `column_map` as our guide, we create a new `inner` dictionary, associating keys from `key_list` with values from `value_list`.

**EDIT**

For a fully-dynamic solution, you can create `column_map` on the fly by comparing the column headers from `file1` with those from `file2`

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

joined_data = dict()
column_map = defaultdict(list)

with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    kh = next(f1).strip()
    vh = next(f2).strip()
    key_headers = kh.split(',')
    value_headers = vh.split(',')

    [column_map[k].append(v) for k in key_headers[1:] for v in value_headers[1:] if v.startswith(k)]
    joined_data['ID'] = dict(column_map)

    key_list = list(csv.DictReader(f1, fieldnames=key_headers))
    value_list = list(csv.DictReader(f2, fieldnames=value_headers))

for kl, vl in zip(key_list, value_list):
    inner = {}
    for key, value_list in column_map.items():
        if kl[key]:
            inner[kl[key]] = [vl[el] for el in value_list]

    joined_data[kl['ID']] = inner
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to aggregate rows from two csv files:

```
>>> list(zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))   # assume 1, 2, 3 /  4, 5, 6 as row values
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

---

```
import csv

new_data_dict = {}
with open('file1.csv') as f1, open('file2.csv') as f2:
    reader1, reader2 = csv.reader(f1), csv.reader(f2)
    for row1, row2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
        id_, map1, map2 = row1
        new_data_dict[id_] = {map1: row2[1:3]}
        map2 = map2.strip()
        if map2:  # put map2 only if map2 key exists
            new_data_dict[id_][map2] = row2[3]
```

---

`new_data_dict` becomes:

```
{'ID': {'map1': ['map1Val1', 'map1Val2'], 'map2': 'map2Val2'},
 'a': {'x1': ['a1', 'a2'], 'x2': 'l1'},
 'b': {'y1': ['b1', 'b2']},
 'c': {'z1': ['c1', 'c2'], 'z2  ': 'n1'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I like @waterboy5281 's answer better because it's more dynamic.